# Could not debug other project included in current project of same solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have added two projects in same solution and I have added reference of one project in other project when I try to debug code of startup project I can able to debug but when code reach the place where it uses function from other project (which I have added as reference from same solution) It is not debugging function from referred project.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the dll and then adding again from Add Reference. Also clean the solution and rebuild.